# iPad - Simultaneous recognition of the same gesture

Tags: ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I need have a view where users can draw multiple rectangles. Now I need to be able to move those rectangles using a Pan gesture. The problem I am having is that I can move any single rectangle with the Pan gesture recognizer with no problem. Now when I use 2 fingers to Pan 2 rectangles to move simultaneously it doesn't work.

Seem to me that the problem is the target/action that I specified for the pan gesture gets fired only once.

My view adopts the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and has defined this delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{   
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add gesture recognizer to each created rectangle view individually by making a method.

like this

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizersToPiece:(UIView *)piece
{
  // Add the gesture recognizer to the piece here
}
```

You can loop in to add the gesture recognizer to all the pieces simultaneously, or while u create each rectangle, just fire this method after creating the rectangle, and passing that as the piece parameter to this function.

That should help.